# Bigger logo without affecting other elements in the navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

My main problem is with a logo. Below is my header element where I attached my navbar and logo.  The Header contains a background image and in it I placed my navbar.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-faded">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.svg" /></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-brand > img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

It looks like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3xPj.png)

And when I specify width for the logo (like `20em`), it becomes bigger but it moves the `li` items too. I don't want my `li` items be affected. Plus I want the logo to be responsive when I specify width it still remains the same in smaller screens.

[iamge2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXHtj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented a lot with logo sizes on bootstrap3 navbar.
For me this works best.

First I give the navbar my desired height, and set the li > a line-height to the same height, so the link padding-top and padding-bottom are fixed (links are vertical centered).

```
.navbar {
    min-height: 100px;
}
ul.navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

The navbar now is 100px height. With padding in mind my logo should now have a max-height of 80px cause we need 10px padding-top and 10px for padding-bottom. Lets say the logo has a width of 200px and a height of 80px, I give the img the class logo.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="#" class="logo" alt=""></a>
```

Now keep the padding in mind, I add 10px of padding-top to the logo.

```
img.logo {
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}
```

If you want different logo sizes, just change the navbar min-height/line-height and change the logo width/padding.

**Bootstrap 3 fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/yghg5hsx/

**Bootstrap 4 fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/973Lde7j/3/

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am using bootstrap 4 not 3, I have been used to 3 but my company wants to move on with 4

Comment: It's the same for bootstrap 4. I updated the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/973Lde7j/3/

Answer (score 0):

put your logo inside a div and the rest of the navbar content in another div

then try this:

```
#navbar { width:100%}

#logoDiv { width:20% }
#contentDiv { width:80% }
```